Can a person under 18 years old e-File, Direct File or Free File US Taxes?
While I could use my desktop tax software to fill my daughter's tax return for 2023.... is there an option for her to do it herself?
IRS Direct File looks OK work, except it requires an ID.me account which requires age 18.
Do any of the online tax filing services allow minors?  Those with a free level for simple returns?
Yes I'm aware of the filing thresholds, that's not the question here.  This is about fiscal learning not the most efficient way to get it done.

Did you try Free File Fillable Forms?

An adult will have to countersign the return anyway... so I'd suggest you treat this as your filing on the kid's behalf, let her enter all the data, then you check and sign it. I think you can set up a second ID.ME account to give her a separate password...
